# R. Data.table. How to diff columns with the same names for two different data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, key

I have two data.tables.

```
dt1 <- data.table("Symbol1" = c("EURUSD", "USDCAD", "EURUSD", "CADJPY"), "Volume" = c(1, 10, 2, 20)) 
dt2 <- data.table("Symbol" = c("EURUSD", "USDCAD"), "Description" = c("Euro vs Dollar", "Canadian vs Dollar"), key = "Symbol")
```

I want to add a new column "Description" for the first data.table from the second one (where "Symbol" is key ) by reference.
I try use the next way:

```
dt1[, Description := dt2[.(Symbol1), Description]]
```

And this works fine. I've got the result

```
dt1
Symbol1 Volume        Description
1:  EURUSD      1     Euro vs Dollar
2:  USDCAD     10 Canadian vs Dollar
3:  EURUSD      2     Euro vs Dollar
4:  CADJPY     20               <NA>
```

But if these two data.tables have the same column name (Symbol)

```
dt1 <- data.table("Symbol" = c("EURUSD", "USDCAD", "EURUSD", "CADJPY"), "Volume" = c(1, 10, 2, 20)) 
dt2 <- data.table("Symbol" = c("EURUSD", "USDCAD"), "Description" = c("Euro vs Dollar", "Canadian vs Dollar"), key = "Symbol")
dt1[, Description := dt2[.(Symbol), Description]]
```

I've got the error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt1, , `:=`(Description, dt2[.(Symbol), Description])) : 
  Supplied 2 items to be assigned to 4 items of column 'Description'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

Is there any way to make it work correctly?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second trial, it fails because the `Symbol` in `dt2[.(Symbol), Description]` is from `dt2`, not from `dt1`. In you first trial, `Symbol1` is not found in `dt2` so R will try to search `dt1` for `Symbol1`. (If this fails too, R will try to search the global environment for `Symbol1`. Therefore, orders matter here.)

I would do it this way:

```
dt1 <- data.table("Symbol1" = c("EURUSD", "USDCAD", "EURUSD", "CADJPY"), "Volume" = c(1, 10, 2, 20)) 
dt2 <- data.table("Symbol" = c("EURUSD", "USDCAD"), "Description" = c("Euro vs Dollar", "Canadian vs Dollar"), key = "Symbol")

dt1[dt2, Description := i.Description, on = .(Symbol1 = Symbol)]

dt1 <- data.table("Symbol" = c("EURUSD", "USDCAD", "EURUSD", "CADJPY"), "Volume" = c(1, 10, 2, 20)) 
dt2 <- data.table("Symbol" = c("EURUSD", "USDCAD"), "Description" = c("Euro vs Dollar", "Canadian vs Dollar"), key = "Symbol")

dt1[dt2, Description := i.Description, on = .(Symbol)]
```

Another workaround is to use get and tell it explicitly where to search for `Symbol`. For example:

```
dt1[Symbol != "EURUSD", Description := dt2[.(get('Symbol', env = sys.parent(3))), Description]]
dt1
#    Symbol Volume        Description
# 1: EURUSD      1               <NA>
# 2: USDCAD     10 Canadian vs Dollar
# 3: EURUSD      2               <NA>
# 4: CADJPY     20               <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a way to explicitly specify which table the column is taken from? (except dt1$ or dt2$ - because I want to use this for the cases where i filter data from dt1. (example: dt1[Symbol != "EURUSD", Description := dt2[.(Symbol), Description]])

Comment: Thanks! It works well! (Maybe there is exists a way to make this code more pretty?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` :

```
library(data.table)

merge.data.table(dt1, dt2, by = 'Symbol', all.x = TRUE)

#   Symbol Volume        Description
#1: CADJPY     20               <NA>
#2: EURUSD      1     Euro vs Dollar
#3: EURUSD      2     Euro vs Dollar
#4: USDCAD     10 Canadian vs Dollar
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But merge operation creates a new copy. But I would like to add a new column by reference without copying.